# Old record shows the converted currency to EUR instead of showing the amount in USD

Tags: trigger, currency

I have a field in Opportunity named List Price Summary that computes and displays the SUM of the Total Price in all its Opportunity Line Item records through trigger.

For example, I have two Opportunity Line Item records, the SUM of their total Price is $200 which is 181.64 if converted to EUR. So my List Price Summary field should display USD 200(EUR 181.64). However, the field displays USD 181.64(EUR 164.96). Is there anything I need to add in my trigger for it to work on old records that I updated? It works fine if I create new records. I tried to use convertCurrency() method but it isn't working with aggregates. Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Note: The corporate Currency of the org is EUR and the record currency is USD.

Comment: Did you change the currency of old records?